# Vue 3 removes white-space between inline-block elements

Tags: vuejs3

Vue 3 removes the white-space between inline-block elements. This means I'll have to go back through quite a few of my sites and update the CSS before I can safely upgrade from version 2. Is there a way to turn this off?

See the following for an example:

```
<ol>
    <li style="display: inline-block"><a href="#">A</a> &raquo; </li>
    <li style="display: inline-block"><a href="#">B</a></li>
</ol>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/27vwLn6u/

Here's the same example in Vue 2:

https://jsfiddle.net/3d0jcnmf/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is now supported since Vue 3.1.0. See https://github.com/vuejs/core/pull/1600 for more information.

Basically now you need to add the following when creating the app:

```
app.config.compilerOptions.whitespace = 'preserve';
```

Here's the updated example:

https://jsfiddle.net/bscz2306/

Comment: But it breaks other stuff that has whitespaces like slots.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you already found the answer at
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/2431#issuecomment-712451346

---

V3 automatically condenses the white space.

You can get around it by using a single line.

```html
<div id="app">
  <ol>
      <li style="display: inline"><a href="#">A</a> &raquo; </li>
      <li style="display: inline"><a href="#">B</a></li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
      <li style="display: inline-block"><a href="#">A</a> &raquo; </li> <li style="display: inline-block"><a href="#">B</a></li>
  </ol>
  {{foo}}
</div>
```

I was looking into the code, and looks like `pre` tags are handled differently, but I haven't found a way to pass `isPreTag` to the component.

Comment: Thanks, but this is still a hack. I'll leave it open for now to see if anyone else has any other suggestions.

Comment: I have a browser inline markdown component and it's totally unusable at this time with Vue 3 because of this issue.