# Nuxt/Vue 3 devour spaces-characters in template. Bug or Feature?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have Nuxt3 app. Default installation.

app.vue file:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>
      <a href="#">AAA</a>
      <a href="#">BBB</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      AAA
      BBB
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Render this template is on this image:

[image]

With `<a>` tag is no space between AAA and BBB. Why? This behaviour is only if I use tags on end and begin of line.

I try set up `compilerOption` `whitespace` in `tsconfig.json` file but no changes.

```json
{
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
  
  "compilerOptions": {
      "whitespace": "preserve"
  }
}
```

Where is the problem? Is it bug of feature?

Comment: With no `typescript` tag, it's hard to understand why `tsconfig` might make a difference (although I know very little about vue3). [This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68393776/14357) looks very similar (w/o the nuxt bit)

Comment: Yes, you right, this settings is only for `typescript`.

Answer (score 1):

The right place for set up `compilerOptions` is file `nuxt.config.(ts|js)`

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    devtools: { enabled: true },
    vue: {
        compilerOptions: {
            whitespace: "preserve"
        }
    }
  
})
```